# Create Thing with Flattr API and OAuth2 PHP Http Post - 404 Not Found Header

Tags: php, oauth, http-post, oauth-2.0, flattr

I got a Problem. I'm trying to call `POST https://api.flattr.com/rest/v2/things` with url, title, description and tags - post parameters but it is not possible to create a thing..

The header returns `404 Not Found` instead of `201 Created`. I'm doing everything right. Look here: http://developers.flattr.net/api/resources/things/#create-a-thing

And yeah, I got the right scope and it is an authorized call..

Answer (score 0):

According to this swedish tweet by another of the Flattr devs this should now be working again: https://twitter.com/#!/simongate/status/168653195676098560